# Multivariate normal with diagonal variance implies its components are normally distributed.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question that seems intuitive but I am not sure how to prove it. Let $X$ be a random vector with componants $X=[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma = diag(\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_n^2)$ and $\mu = [\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n]$. How can I properly show that $X_i\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$  (and that they are independent)?

Comment: Do you also need to show the $X_i$s are independent? Since otherwise you don't need $\Sigma$ to be diagonal.

Comment: Yes I need to show they are independent as well

Comment: "Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$", What's your definition for that, (for a rv $X$ to follow a multivariate normal distribution) ?

Comment: I would have thought being multivariate normal implied any linear combinations of its components (including simple ones) were normally distributed, no matter what the covariance matrix was.  In this case a diagonal covariance matrix then implies independence

Answer (score 2):

if the $\Sigma$ matrix is diagonal it means that all the covariances are zero. In a gaussian model, incorrelation and independence are equivalent thus

$$f_{X_1X_2\dots X_n}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdot f_{X_2}(x_2)\cdot \dots \cdot f_{X_n}(x_n)$$

Comment: "In a gaussian model, incorrelation and independence are equivalent" - this is what they won't to prove I think.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ be a Gaussian vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent then obviously $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Conversely, if $\Sigma$ is diagonal, then for all $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we can compute the characteristic function
$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(i\langle u, X\rangle\right)\right] &=\exp\left(i\langle u, \mu\rangle - \frac{u^\top \Sigma u}{2}\right)\\&=\exp\left(i\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\mu_k - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^nu_k^2\sigma_k^2}{2}\right) \\ &=\prod_{k=1}^n\exp\left(iu_k\mu_k -\frac{\sigma_k^2u_k^2}{2}\right) \\ &=\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(u_kX_k\right)\right]\end{align}$$
hence independence.

Taking $u$ to be the vector with $0$ everywhere except at the $k$-th position where there's a $1$ shows that for all $k=1,...,n$ the component $X_k$ has the characteristic function of a $\mathcal{N}(\mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$ random variable.